# Plotting function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having a problem plotting the following function in Matlab:

```
x = 10*((sin(pi*f*0.1))/(pi*f*0.1))^2;
```

I am using this code:

```
f = -50:0.1:50;
x = 10*((sin(pi*f*0.1))/(pi*f*0.1))^2;
plot (f,x);
```

I can plot the function using a graph tool I found on google but MATLAB is just giving me a blank plot. The axis don't correspond to what I should be getting either.

Does anyone know why this graph doesn't appear as it should?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [element-wise division (`./`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) rather than [`mrdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) (`/`) which attempts to solve a linear system. Similarly, you need to use the element-wise [`power` (`.^`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) rather than the matrix power, [`mpower` (`^`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html).

```
x = 10 * ((sin(pi * f * 0.1)) ./ (pi * f * 0.1)).^2;
```

The `.` in the operator is subtle and not necessary when working with scalars; however you must use it if you want element-wise behavior when working with multi-dimensional arrays.

Also to be consistent with common conventions, I'd recommend switching `f` and `x` so you have a function `f(x)`

```
x = -50:0.1:50;
f = 10 * ((sin(pi * x * 0.1)) ./ (pi * x * 0.1)).^2;
plot(x, f)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect he was the other answerer with the same answer

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Hahah I figured. Grumpy people :)

Comment: @smith1993  if this answer solves your problem, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking the [**`✓`**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) mark on the left side of this answer.

Comment: @smith1993 if this answers your question, please consider to accept this answer. Thanks :) upvote by me as compensation as well :)